# Errors during bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All of a sudden I've been getting the following error when trying to do a bundle install.

```
/Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/core_ext/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb:76: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendored_thor.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: "All of a sudden" -- did you add a new gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$end` is end-of-file, so it seems that your environment is broken, the vendored `thor` gem inside `bundler` to be more specific. Maybe you should try to reinstall `bundler` first.

```
gem install bundler
```

PS: The most recent version of bundler is 1.1.3. So you can install that if you're fine with it (I'd recommend it) or you can reinstall your old version using `gem install bundler -v 1.0.21`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I completely forgot to run this before I posted my question. Seems to be working now.